# Ambient Light Sensor Samsung Series 9

Tags: drivers, sensors

Have Fedora 19 running on my Samsung series 9. Got everything working with the exception of the ambient light sensor controlling keyboard backlight and screen brightness.

Forums around the net show users having success on Ubuntu, so I'm wondering if there are any pointers on how this is implemented? Is it a hardware only control or do I need specific kernel drivers etc.

Apologies for the vague question, but I can't find much out via Google and `/sys` and friends don't contain anything light related I can script as far as I can see.

Comment: Is the samsung_laptop module loaded?

Comment: Yes it is loaded

Comment: Then, AFAIK, you should have the relevant directrories in `/sys`. Be aware, though, that this module was responsible for bricking machines that were UEFI booted. Subsequent kernels had patches that fixed the issue; but this *may* have broken the backlighting... I just blacklisted that module when I first installed Linux on my laptop.

Comment: I turned off UEFI in the bios iirc. No ambient light stuff in sys tho, pretty much everything else is in there.

Comment: Like I said, I suspect (and that is all it is, a suspicion) the changes to remove the bricking behaviour also killed the backlight. There is a [thread on the Arch boards](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147094) where others are experiencing the same thing. It's the price we pay for running newer kernels :)

Comment: Thanks @jsonwryan, but the backlight is fine, it's the ambient light sensor that doesn't seem to have a driver component. I'll take a ganders at the samsung platform source in the kernel.

Comment: Sorry, my backlight works fine as well; I was referring to the fancy keyboard backlighting...